# Server don't accept the parameters from my raw POST HTTP Protocol call

Tags: php, post

This is the raw POST call that im sending to the server (I'm using `Postman REST Client`):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: ******
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 9

key=value
```

On the server side I want to read they *key,value* inside $_POST from my raw POST call, PHP source looks like this:

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
  header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' );
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
  header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  print_r($_POST);
  echo file_get_contents('php://input');
?>
```

This is the output that I get back from the server:

```
Array
(

)
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: ******
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 9

key=value
```

*Update:*
Also did same call to [posttestserver.com](http://www.posttestserver.com/) with same [result](http://posttestserver.com/data/2015/03/04/15.43.331055724674)

**Why is the $_POST array empty, what am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but I'd say the client your using isn't sending the data properly. I'm thinking it's not using the proper CRLF in the request and/or it's cause it's not sending `Connection: close`. It could also be a misconfiguration in your web server.

I tested it out by myself using the following PHP script:

```
<?php

$host = 'www.example.com';
if ($fp = fsockopen('ssl://'. $host, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30)) {
    $data = 'key=value';

    $msg = "POST /test.php HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $msg .= "Host: ".$host."\r\n";
    $msg .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $msg .= "Connection: close\r\n";
    $msg .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= $data."\r\n\r\n";

    $response = '';

    if ( fwrite($fp, $msg) ) {
            echo 'Request:'.PHP_EOL;
            echo $msg;

            while ( !feof($fp) ) {
                    $response .= fgets($fp, 4096);
            }

            echo 'Response:'.PHP_EOL;
            echo $response;
     }
     fclose($fp);

}
```

And I got the expected response from the exact same PHP script you posted:

```
Request:
POST /test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: close
Content-Length: 9

key=value

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2015 05:06:53 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.6
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 05 Mar 2015 05:06:53 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate

26
Array
(
    [key] => value
)
key=value
0
```